# More than a ASP:Wizard control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can one have more than a Wizard control on the same page without the "RequiredFieldValidator" will affect the other Wizard control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx) property on all validators that should be grouped together, and call the [Page.Validate(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwzxc386.aspx) with the name of the validation group you want to validate.

You may need to disable clientside validation for this to work properly.

Comment: what if you want to use java script for one of those when to submit?

Comment: You would need to write the javascript validation yourself by calling Page_ClientValidate("groupName"). You could build your own Button-control that would render the necessary code yourself.